# Creating a thread pool to handle network connections

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Below is example of the image thread I'm using, which is called every time there is an image to be shown. I use code similar to this to do other network connecctions as well. 
The problem, I suspect to my performances issues, is my lack of thread pooling.

If a multiple or many of these threads are created before they finish, are they not existing at the same time, invariably decreasing performance?

How would I implement Thread Pooling? I've seen the term being floated around, but I've failed to find a good simple example of it being implemented.

```
public class ImageThread extends Thread {
    private String url;
    private HttpConnection httpConn;
    private InputStream is;
    private JSONArray array;
    private Bitmap image;
    private ImageThreadCallback c;


    private static boolean hasImageCache = false;
    private static MultiMap imageCache;

    public ImageThread(String url, ImageThreadCallback c, String ident){
        System.out.println("Connection begin!");
        this.url = url;
        this.c = c;

    }

    public void notifyUs(){
        this.c.update(image);
    }


    public void run(){

        myConnectionFactory connFact = new myConnectionFactory();
        ConnectionDescriptor connDesc;

        connDesc = connFact.getConnection(url);
        System.out.println("Connection factory!");
        if(connDesc != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Connection not null!");
            httpConn = (HttpConnection) connDesc.getConnection();
            try {
                httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            is = null;



            try
            {
                final int iResponseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                       System.out.println("Connection in run!");
                         // Get InputConnection and read the server's response
                        InputConnection inputConn = (InputConnection) httpConn;
                        try {
                            is = inputConn.openInputStream();
                            System.out.println("Connection got inputstream!");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        byte[] data = null;
                        try {
                            data = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);
                            System.out.println("Connection got data!");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                         EncodedImage hai = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(data, 0, data.length);

                        image = hai.getBitmap();
                        notifyUs();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Other than not thread pooling, is there anything problematic with my code? I've avoided the ui event thread by creating a thread like this?

Answer (score 0):

> Other than not thread pooling, is there anything problematic with my code?

Also, make sure you are `close()`ing your `InputConnection` and `HttpConnection` objects in a `finally` block at the end of your `run()` method. Some older BlackBerry OS versions had problems where this could keep threads from finishing and being garbage collected.

Answer (score -1):

> If a multiple or many of these threads are created before they finish, are they not existing at the same time, invariably decreasing performance?

Yes, if there are many threads running concurrently the context switches between them might hit the overall performance, especially if those threads aren't doing much. Additionally creating threads is also quite costly. Thread pooling might help here since you'd only create a reasonable number of threads that runs concurrently and those threads could be "reused", i.e. when they have finished their tasks they can execute other tasks if some exist.

> How would I implement Thread Pooling? I've seen the term being floated around, but I've failed to find a good simple example of it being implemented.

Start out with `ThreadPoolExecutor` and it's [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

A few annotations as well:

- class names should by convention start with an upper case letter (`myConnectionFactory`)
- depending on what the connection factory does, you might want to use a single instance (however you should then synchronize access where needed)
- if multiple threads share one `ImageThreadCallback` instance, you might need some synchronization (ideally not on the whole method but on any internal writes it makes, this however, depends on the implementation).

Comment: I don't think this is available for blackberry. Is it possible to run every image download as a TimerTask and add it to a Timer object which is a single thread and would automatically queue it? I found that as a solution in another post, but I'm not sure if that is an accepted approach.

Comment: @Adam That might be a solution but I've not used it yet. Besides that, if the blackberry only has one or 2 cores (as most phones have these days) creating more that 2 threads might already hurt performance. Thus using a queue and a single thread to download the images might be a good idea.

Comment: you mention a single instance of connectionFactory. Would I instantiate that when the app loads up? How would I make it available for all my threads and classes. Sorry, this inquiry is probably java 101.

Comment: @Adam you could pass the factory to the thread/task constructor as a parameter. And you might instantiate when you need to pass it at latest. As I said, it depends on what the factory actually does. You _might_ want to use a shared instance but there may also be reasons not to do so.